# Regex for ^A and ^S ? Not able sed or grep it?

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have a file which contains this line.

Input

```
sls="N" stnid="armID"
sls="N" stnid="C-ARM #11 w^Aw^Aw^A^Sg^Aw"
sls="N" stnid="virtualID"
```

For I which I want an output like

```
sls="N" stnid="armID"
sls="N" stnid=""
sls="N" stnid="virtualID"
```

I want to sed  "C-ARM #11 w^Aw^Aw^A^Sg^Aw" and replace it with a blank.

The issue is that there is no regular expression I could find which will replace it.

I have tried sed -e s//^//g s/A//g  myfile > newfile.

It didn't work.

One more issue is that when I CAT myfile, it doesnt show me the ^A & ^S characters.
File looks like this.

```
sls="N" stnid="armID"
sls="N" stnid="C-ARM #11 wwwgw"
sls="N" stnid="virtualID"
```

Please help, thanks in Advance.

Pal

Comment: If you don't see them when you `cat` the file, they're `control-A` characters, not `^` followed by `A`.

Answer (score 1):

^A and ^S are text representations of non-printable ASCII characters. The strings do not actually contain the substrings "^A" and "^S". I believe ^A is ascii code 1 and ^S is 19. To include raw ASCII characters in your sed input, use $(echo "\001") and $(echo "\013").

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those are control characters (`^A` is actually the non-printing character with ASCII code 1).  I can think of two ways to deal with this.  First, try matching the

```
# If you get the pattern of characters right, this will work:
sed -e 's/C-ARM #11 w.w.w..g.w//' myfile > newfile

# This will be less precise, but should still work:
sed -e 's/C-ARM #11 .*"/"/' myfile > newfile
```

Or use `cat` to convert those non-printing characters to printing characters, then use `sed`:

```
cat -A myfile > myfile.fixed
sed -e 's/C-ARM #11 w^Aw^Aw^A^Sg^Aw//' myfile.fixed > newfile
```